# java stream api and transactional batch processing

Tags: jpa, stream, transactional

I would realy like to save entities in a batch using one transaction, like this:

```
    @Transactional
public <T extends EntityInterface> Stream<T> batchSave(Stream<T> entities, Integer flushCount) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    return entities.map((t) -> {
        if (t.isTransient()) {
            em.persist(t);
            return t;
        } else {
            return em.merge(t);
        }
    });
}
```

But unfortunately stream processing looses the transaction. Is there any way to make this work?

Bye

Comment: Wonder what "getEntityManager" does ...

Comment: it gets an injected EntityManager, a subclass injects it, the super has a protected getEntityManager